# Cmd module: async job prints are overwriting prompt input

Tags: python, asynchronous, cmd, printing

I have trouble describing this problem properly. I'm writing a CLI with the `cmd` module that starts asynchronous jobs. When these jobs are printing some output with `print`, then that print will overwrite the current prompt / user input.

Here's a code snippet describing that problem:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import cmd


class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    workers = {}

def work(self, name):
    for n in range(1, 11):
        print(name + ': I am on number ' + str(n) + ' of 10')
        time.sleep(3)

def do_add(self, line):
    self.workers.update({line: self.POOL.submit(self.work, line)})

def do_list(self, line):
    print(str(list(self.workers.keys())))

def do_EOF(self, line):
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyCmd().cmdloop()
```

After you have activated the CLI, you can add jobs with `add some_string`, e.g. `add lucy`, `add peter`. With `list` you will get a list of started jobs. These jobs will start printing stuff to the CLI, but they will overwrite your input. Try spamming `list` and you'll notice it, here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of CLI output]

Obviously, I don't want the prompt to be overwritten. The last line of the CLI should always be `(Cmd) some-user-input`. I'm open for code suggestions and different modules/libraries.

Comment: If I use the lines `self.stdout.write(self.prompt)` and `self.stdout.flush()` after printing, I can enforce the last line of CLI to always be (Cmd). However, this will get messy if the work is actually being done outside of the class. Also, it would be nice to reuse the user input after generating a new (Cmd) line.